# How to configure Portforwarding on KVM Hypervisor?

Tags: linux-kvm, qemu, libvirt

I have a Debian install 3.2.68 with KVM/qemu/libvirt as hypervisor.

In "/etc/network/interfaces" I only see eth0 with my static ip, but if I enter "ifconfig" I see also an "virbr0" interface with the ip: 192.168.122.1

The virtual-machines gets dynamic IPs like: 192.168.122.155 with the 192.168.122.1 as gateway.

My Question is:

In which file can I configure the ip and dhcp settings for the virbr0 interface?

How can I set a portforwarding from the static address from the hypervisor to one of the virtual-machines?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Please clarify which Debien release you’re using. Check `/etc/debian_version`.

Comment: Debian release: 7.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For IP and DHCP settings, this is answered in e.g. https://serverfault.com/questions/627238/kvm-libvirt-how-to-configure-static-guest-ip-addresses-on-the-virtualisation-ho

For port forwarding, see e.g. https://serverfault.com/questions/140622/how-can-i-port-forward-with-iptables

Comment: 1. works perfect, realy easy - 2. i think this is the right solution, i am just a little bit strugeling with the configuration, but this ist a diffrent question ;)

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/930305/how-to-configure-portforwarding-with-iptabels

Answer (score 0):

As per https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/124681/how-to-ssh-from-host-to-guest-using-qemu, this can be configured with the help of `-redir tcp:8022::22` and/or `-net user,hostfwd=tcp::8022-:22` options of `kvm`.